# How to restore a db in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

i tried to restore a db using mongorestore but i get this error:

```
    2020-09-14T18:48:59.210+0200    error parsing command line options: error parsing positional arguments: provide only one polling interval in seconds and only one MongoDB connection string. Connection strings must begin with mongodb:// or mongodb+srv:// schemes
2020-09-14T18:48:59.258+0200    try 'mongorestore --help' for more information
```

I tried a lot of combinations, like this:

```
mongorestore -h localhost -d projectdb C:\Users\leo\Downloads\project\projectdbfiles
```

But without success.. i read the documentation and i tried to use --host:host and /host:host..

Im using windows

Comment: What's the exact command you used?

Answer (score 1):

Below solution worked for me

Copy **mongorestore.exe** to **C:\Users\leo\Downloads\project** folder

open command prompt C:\Users\leo\Downloads\project\ location

> mongoservice.exe projectdbfiles\

it should work.